# mod_rewrite config for /

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` config

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule \.git - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^help help.php [L]
RewriteRule ^home home.php [L]
RewriteRule ^profile profile.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+) profile.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ profile.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Now, whenever somebody visits the landing page, they get redirected using the last rule for `profile.php?u=$1`.

How do I change the configuration so that `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/` are mapped to index.php and not profile.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the empty string or single slash just after the `^index` rule:

```
RewriteRule ^help help.php [L]
RewriteRule ^home home.php [L]
RewriteRule ^profile profile.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index index.php [L]
# Match root request with optional slash
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Pity I can accept the answer only after 8 minutes. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest not to do it this way.

Instead, simply user this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will send all your requests to index.php page, from there create a router.php and pass on the requests to that page, using php.

but in case you do, just add

```
 RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]
```

Like Michael suggested.

Here is a simple tool to test your rules, if you wish to

[Apache RewriteRule tester](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/)